# Как поменять неизвестную кодировку на utf-8?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Мне приходит (от фронтенда) строка вида `Привееееееет`. Если записать ее напрямую в базу, то получится `????????????`. Как перевести такую строку в неизвестном формате в формат, пригодный для `mysql` ?

Comment: От фронтенда строка приходит в таком виде или только отправляется? Если приходит, то это правится фильтром для принимающего сервлета. Если же приходит нормально, то для mysql задается кодировка (1. SET NAMES 'utf8';   2.SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'; 3. SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci')

Comment: @carapuz я отправляю через `AngularJS` и смотрю, что принял сервлет. Принтуется коректное сообщение, но в базу пишутся знаки вопросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
String result = Arrays.toString(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

str - твоя приходящая строка. Попробуй узнать в какой кодировке присылают или подобрать.